# Swift: How to make my character in my game only be able to jump once he hits the ground?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game where my character jumps from land to land. I have everything down and done except my remaining problem is if you keep tapping the screen he can keep jumping forever. I want it so he has to hit the ground before he can jump again.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    struct PhysicsCatagory {
        static let Knight : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
        static let land : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    }

    var Knight = SKSpriteNode()
    var land = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CJLand4")
```

This is my current code that makes him jump:

```
Knight.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
Knight.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 325))
```

I have this under `touchesBegan` and it adds gravity and on impulse it allows him to jump. But I only want him to be able to jump once every time he hits land. Please help if you can.

Comment: You may track collision with land with a boolean and set it false after a jump occured.

Comment: @the4kman so something along the lines of touchedLand = false? Could you give me an example in code

Answer (score 1):

You can check if vertical velocity is 0, and Knight only jump if are landing. It really depends on the type of jump you are looking for.

```
if Knight.physicsBody?.velocity.y == 0 { Jump() }
```

Comment: This is my favorite solution,  I recommend doing this as long as knight does not double jump

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a BOOL property to your scene called something like `isJumping` which is initialised to `false`.

Then, in `touchesBegan` check to see if `isJumping` is true. If not, perform the jump and set `isJumping` to `true`.

When the jump is over (knight has contacted the ground), set `isJumping` back to `false`.

Comment: I recommend doing this method in combination with the other method if your knight does have a double jump feature,  The problem with single jump is if isJumping = false, and the knight falls,  he can still jump in the air